# pandas: get top n including the duplicates of a sorted column

Tags: pandas

I have some data like

This is a table sorted by score column and also then by cat column

```
score   cat
18      B
18      A
17      A
16      B
16      A
15      B
14      B
13      A
12      A
10      B
9       B
```

I want to get the top 5 of score including the duplicates and also add the rank

i.e

```
rank    score   cat
1       18      B
1       18      A
2       17      A
3       16      B
3       16      A
4       15      B
5       14      B
```

How can i get this using pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the data frame is ordered, try `factorize`

```
df['rnk'] = df.score.factorize()[0]+1
out = df[df['rnk'] <= 5]
out
   score cat  rnk
0     18   B    1
1     18   A    1
2     17   A    2
3     16   B    3
4     16   A    3
5     15   B    4
6     14   B    5
```

Comment: I also want to add rank column. Can you check the edited question